# Upload file from Angular 9 to NestJs

Tags: angular, typescript, file-upload, nestjs, multer

I'm having very hard time to upload a file into my backend (nestJs). I don't understand how my FileInterceptor reads the "fieldName" set as a Multer Option.

Here's my mediaService (front)

```
/* Upload an image into the server */
uploadImage(image: File) {
  const formData = new FormData();
  formData.append('file', image);
  return this.http.post<any>(`${this.serverUrl}/medias`, { formData });
}
```

Looks very simple, but my server doesnt save the image, and return undefined.

Here's my API endpoint for file upload

```
@Post()
    @UseInterceptors(
        FileInterceptor('file', {
            storage: diskStorage({
                destination: './public/upload',
                filename: editFileName,

            }),
            fileFilter: imageFileFilter,
        }),
    )
    async uploadedImage(
        @UploadedFile() file
    ) {
        return this.mediasService.create(new MediaDto(data))
    }
```

Why my fileInterceptor cannot read the "file" key of my formData ? If I send an image using Postman, name the key file, it works as expected, the file is saved into my storage destination.

Already tried a bunch of different approach, with "multiform-data" headers, changing key name etc ..

Any help would be very appreciated

Thanks !

Comment: Facing same issue working with postman but not working with angular post request